# Writing to a log file using log4j

Tags: java, servlets, log4j

I have a problem and an uncertainty relating to using Log4j.

1. I can't write the log to a file. I only get a warning that says:

`log4j:WARN No such property [file] in org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.`

Logging to console works fine.

1. I want to store the log file outside the context root. In this case, would I hard code the absolute path into the properties file? Sorry if that's a dumb question.

**Log4j.properties**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/Users/me/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/wtpwebapps/my_app/log.txt
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**LogInit.java**

```
String root = Environment.getRootDirectory(getServletContext());
    String propertiesUri = root + propertiesUriParameter;
    File propertiesFile = new File(propertiesUri);
    if (!propertiesFile.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing log4j with: " + propertiesUri);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(propertiesUri);
    }
```

Comment: Is there an error message? The path in `log4j.appender.file.File=Users/Me/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/wtpwebapps/my_app/log.txt` is missing a leading `/` by the way (are you on OS X?).

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. I've put that in and the code still doesn't work. I get this warning: `INFO
log4j:WARN No such property [file] in org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this from :

log4j.appender.file.File=Users/Me/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/wtpwebapps/my_app/log.txt

To

log4j.appender.file.File=/Users/Me/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/wtpwebapps/my_app/log.txt

And make sure below path exists

/Users/Me/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/wtpwebapps/my_app/

Regards,

Shiva Kumar SS

Comment: Yeah, the file didn't exist. Thanks for your help :)